# Drawing an SVG at set point with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Title for this is pretty naff but I've been struggling with this for too long to think of an eloquent way to put it.

So, what I have is a timeline of events for the company I work for. Everything is fine except for the SVG which follows the page down on scroll. We have a working version of it currently but it requires far too many lines of code for me to be happy with. I re-wrote it for ~150 lines to this..

```
function drawLines() {
    $.each($("path"), function (i, val) {
        var line = val;
        drawLine($(this), line);
    });
}

function drawLine(container, line) {
    var length = 0;
    var pathLength = line.getTotalLength();
    var distanceFromTop = container.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
    var percentDone = 1 - (distanceFromTop / $(window).height());
    length = percentDone * pathLength;
    line.style.strokeDasharray = [length, pathLength].join(' ');
}
```

Being called on the page by..

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    drawLines()
});
```

This works in the sense that it draws the line on page scroll which is great. But I have some divs that animate in when they are a set position above the bottom of the screen this is handled by..

```
$('.changeL').each(function () {
        if ($window.scrollTop() >= ($(this).offset().top - ($window.height() / 1.1))) {
            $(this).css({ 'left': '0', 'float': 'right' });
        }
        else {
            $(this).css({ 'left': '-1000px' });
        }
    });
```

What I want is for the SVG to be controlled by the above function, something like `$('path).each(function...` so the line is being drawn in the same time the divs are animating in.

Hopefully that makes sense and someone can help me as I am at a total loss as to what to do with it all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Scrollmagic" (https://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/ ) is pretty good for this kind of stuff. Here's its demo for SVG drawing: https://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/examples/advanced/svg_drawing.html

Comment: I came across Scrollmagic earlier but even when essentially copying that code; changing a few bits to fit what I have, it just returns TimelineMax is not defined. Makes no sense to me

Comment: Did you include the GSAP library? (http://greensock.com/get-started-js#loading)

Comment: Just tried that and the same error. I've had nothing but problems with Scrollmagic and after 2 days trying to get this all working I'm running out of time to get it sorted. Do you know of any other libraries that aren't a pain in the backside? Thanks for your help

Comment: when I looked around not long ago, it seemed to be the only one that is still actively supported. For me it works fine

Comment: Damn. Thanks for your help anyway